# How to select element inside open Shadow DOM from Document?

Tags: html, css, shadow-dom

Say I have a DOM that looks like this in my Document:

```
<body>
  <div id="outer">
    <custom-web-component>
      #shadow-root (open)
        <div id="inner">Select Me</div>
    </custom-web-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible to select the inner div inside the shadow root using a single `querySelector` argument on `document`? If so, how is it constructed?

For example, something like `document.querySelector('custom-web-component > #inner')`

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```js
document.querySelector("custom-web-component").shadowRoot.querySelector("#inner")
```

Comment: what if you don't know for certain when particular tags are going to be shadow roots?

Answer (score 3):

This code will behave like query selector and work on nested shadowDoms:

```
const querySelectorAll = (node,selector) => {
    const nodes = [...node.querySelectorAll(selector)],
        nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(node, Node.ELEMENT_NODE);
    let currentNode;
    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
        if(currentNode.shadowRoot) {
            nodes.push(...querySelectorAll(currentNode.shadowRoot,selector));
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Example usage from a mock HTML snippet would be helpful to using this function

Answer (score 1):

It **cannot** be done with a single selector, that capability has been dropped from the web: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/remove-shadow-piercing/

However you can do it by calling `querySelector` recursively. This can be heavy so use the simplest version possible for your case.

##### If you know the exact root already

```js
document.querySelector(".your-root-selector")
.shadowRoot.querySelector(".your-shadowed-selector")
```

##### If you have many roots and many shadowed elements

This will loop through every element on the page, so it's quite heavy. Use judiciously:

```js
const elements = []
for (const {shadowRoot} of document.querySelectorAll("*")) {
    if (shadowRoot) {
        elements.push(...shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".your-shadowed-selector"));
    }
}
```

##### If you have nested roots

This runs recursively, use rarely:

```js
const elements = []
function findElements(root) {
    for (const {shadowRoot} of root.querySelectorAll("*")) {
        if (shadowRoot) {
            // Look for elements in the current root
            elements.push(...shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".your-shadowed-selector"));
            // Look for more roots in the current root
            findElements(shadowRoot);
        }
    }
}
findElements(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, not quite. The TL:DR is that, depending on how the component is set up, you might be able to do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('custom-web-component').div.innerHTML = 'Hello world!';
```

Do do this - if you have access to where the web component is created, you can add an interface there to access inner content. You can do this the same way you would make any JavaScript class variable/method public. Something like:

```js
/**
 *  Example web component
 */
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Create shadow DOM
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    
    // Create mock div - this will be directly accessible from outside the component
    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    
    // And this span will not
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    
    // Append div and span to shadowRoot
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(span);
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(this.div);
  }
}

// Register component
window.customElements.define('custom-web-component', MyComponent);

// You can now access the component 'div' from outside of a web component, like so:
(function() {
  let component = document.querySelector('custom-web-component');
  
  // Edit div
  component.div.innerHTML = 'EDITED';
  
  // Edit span
  component._shadowRoot.querySelector('span').innerHTML = 'EDITED 2';
})();
```

```html
<custom-web-component></custom-web-component>
```

In this instance, you can access the `div` from outside of the component, but the `span` is not accessible.

To add: As web components are encapsulated, I don't think you can otherwise select internal parts of the component - you have to explicitly set a way of selecting them using `this`, as above.

**EDIT:**

Saying that, if you know what the shadow root key is, you can do this: `component._shadowRoot.querySelector()` (*added to demo above*). But then that is quite a weird thing to do, as it sorta goes against the idea of encapsulation.

**EDIT 2**

The above method will only work is the shadow root is set using the `this` keyword. If the shadow root is set as `let shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})` then I don't think you will be able to search for the `span` - may be wrong there though.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful and detailed answer. Unfortunately, I am looking and hoping for a single querySelector argument string, as I am bound to an API that requires that at the moment :(

Comment: That's a shame. I think then the answer is probably no. As above, the closest you'll be able to get is `let innerDiv = document.querySelector('custom-web-component').div`. I am not aware of any other methods.