# Lit Element - add event listener to element inside the component

Tags: lit

I have looked at a number of examples (eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897456/access-a-shadow-root-element-using-document-queryselector)) of this which don't work for me.

A simple Lit component. I would like to add an event listener on the button, selected by its id. The result in the console is null - it can't find the button in the shaddow Dom. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { html, LitElement } from "lit";

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    var buttonElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("myButton");
    console.log(buttonElement);
  }

  render() {
    return html` <button id="myButton">Click</button>`;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

UPDATE:

Putting it here worked.

```
firstUpdated() {
  var buttonElement= this.shadowRoot.getElementById("myButton");
  console.log(buttonElement);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to select it via id? Would ref help in your case, which is imho much more elegant?

Comment: It is just an example. The type of selector is not the issue. However it seems that the shadow dom is not fully rendered at the point of connectedCallback(). Putting it in firstUpdated() worked.

Comment: I was just compiling an example with firstUpdated, while you were answering.

Comment: Side note, for cases like this prefer binding the event declaratively with `@`. For a `click` event use: `@click=${<event listener>}`. If it's a custom event `my-custom-evt`, then `@my-custom-evt` works.

Reference: https://lit.dev/docs/components/events/#adding-event-listeners-in-the-element-template

Lit handles adding and cleaning up events in this case.

Comment: @YouCodeThings Thanks. Yes, that is another way. It is just that project I am working on uses listeners and I was trying to understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

shadowDOM, created in the `constructor` is available in the `connectedCallback`

But in Lit `render` filling your shadowDOM (again) runs (too) late, after the `connectedCallback`

```js
customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
      .innerHTML = `<button>CLICK</button>`;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this
      .shadowRoot
      .querySelector("button")
      .onclick = evt => alert(evt.type +": "+ evt.target.nodeName)
  }
})
```

```html
<my-component></my-component>
```

Note: since its targeting shadowDOM and not DOM, you could set the click handler immediately in the `constructor`

Answer (score 0):

Please use ref if possible. Otherwise you could use firstUpdated.
Also you should use renderRoot instead of shadowRoot, because it's not said, that the renderRoot is always a shadowRoot. See https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/

```html
<script type="module">
import {
  LitElement,
  html
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";
import {
  createRef, ref
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit/directives/ref.js?module";

class MyElement extends LitElement {

  buttonRef = createRef();

  firstUpdated() {
    super.firstUpdated();
    const buttonElement = this.renderRoot.querySelector("#myButton");
    console.log(buttonElement);
    console.log(this.buttonRef.value);
  }

  render() {
    return html` <button id="myButton" ${ref(this.buttonRef)}>Click</button>`;
  }
}

customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
</script>
<my-element></my-element>
```